# How to find the difference between two times?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this code:

```
-(IBAction)startTime:(id)sender {
    NSDate *myDateTime1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", myDateTime1);
    [myDateTime1 release];
}

-(IBAction)stopTime:(id)sender {
    NSDate *myDateTime2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", myDateTime2);
    [myDateTime2 release];
}
```

I would like to find the difference between the two times. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to make the dates ivars. At the moment they do not know of each others existence.

**MyClass.m** (Replace MyClass for whatever your class is called)

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *startDate; // Add an ivar to hold the startDate

@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize startDate = _startDate;

// More of your class

- (void)dealloc;
{
    [_startDate release];
    // release anything else
    [super dealloc];
}

-(IBAction)startTime:(id)sender
{
    self.startDate = [NSDate date];
}

- (IBAction)stopTime:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"%f", [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate]);
}

// More of your class

@end
```

Comment: I think the 'seld' in NSLog must be 'self'. I cannot edit it since it is less than six characters.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [self.stopTime timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: self.startTime];
```

More simply use a convenience method and no release is needed:

```
-(IBAction)startTime:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate date]);
}
```